# No tables found using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hello I want to scrape data from one website. I **scrape** my data with

```
 BeautifulSoup
```

and this the code that I use (without the imports):

```
df = pd.read_html(requests.get('myurl').text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
df.to_csv("mycsv.csv", index=False)
```

So far i don't have problems with this code, but when i want to **scrape** data from this [site](https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1). The above program has an error that says no table found. So i use

```
selenium
```

to solve my problem. Below i have the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\myfolders\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1")
html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables[1]
driver.close()
```

But again when i execute the adove code i have the same problem

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

When i check the html of the [page](https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1) i find the table attributes. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The table is loaded via javascript and takes a while to load. You may need to [wait a bit](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) before getting `driver.page_source`.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for the tables to load before reading `driver.page_source`.
Tested the following on my machine and was able to pick up two tables. You may want to add additional waits depending on your needs.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1")

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'table'))
    )

html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)
driver.close()
print(tables)
```